# How can I divide single values of a dataframe by monthly averages?

Tags: pandas, time-series, average, resampling

I have the following 15 minute data as a `dataframe` for 3 years. With the first two columns being the index.

```
2014-01-01 00:15:00  1269.6      
2014-01-01 00:30:00  1161.6      
2014-01-01 00:45:00  1466.4      
2014-01-01 01:00:00  1365.6      
2014-01-01 01:15:00  1362.6      
2014-01-01 01:30:00  1064.0      
2014-01-01 01:45:00  1171.2      
2014-01-01 02:00:00  1171.0      
2014-01-01 02:15:00  1330.4      
2014-01-01 02:30:00  1309.6      
2014-01-01 02:45:00  1308.4      
2014-01-01 03:00:00  1494.0
```

I have used `resample` to get a second series with monthly averages.

```
data_Monthly = data.resample('1M', how='mean')
```

How can I divide the values in the last column by their monthly average with the result being still a time series on 15 minute granularity?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First make a grouper:

```
import pandas as pd

In [1]: grouper = pd.Grouper(freq="1M")
```

Then make your new column:

```
In [2]: df['normed'] = df.groupby(grouper).transform(lambda x: x/x.mean())
```

By passing grouper to the `groupby` method you group your data into one month chunks.  Within each chunk you divide the 15 minute interval datum by the mean for that month.

Answer (score 11):

I think it is generally recommended to use Grouper instead of TimeGrouper. Have a look at [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html).
For example, if your column is called Date, use

```
grouper = pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='M')
```

instead of using TimeGrouper and then continue as @Zelazny7 suggested.
If your column is not a datetime index then use

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in one line with:

```
df.groupby([df.index.year, df.index.month]).transform(lambda x: x/x.mean())
```

Answer (score 0):

> `data_Monthly = data.resample('M',on='Date').mean()`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please consider explaining your answer alongside the code you provide, as it will only help the SO community to understand how your method works.